# Accessing Page Public Content - App Review Required

Tags: facebook

Trying to use the graph api (via SDK for PHP) to display our own most recent FB post on our own website. I'm new to this company and picking up where a previous developer left off.  According to others, the custom WordPress plugin used to work prior to FB releasing graph 3.0 but now, any calls to graph.facebook.com say that to use 'Page Public Content Access', the endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook.  However, I can't get the plugin to return any posts - even in developer mode - so how do I do a screen recording to show Facebook how I intend to use graph if I can't actually get it to work in order to create the recording?  There has to be something I'm missing, right?

Comment: Your don’t need PPCA, since it is your own page, so you can use a page access token to access the content. You would have to submit your app for review regarding the necessary permission (`manage_pages` is required to get a page token), _if_ you wanted to make the app public. But since this app needs to read data only, it doesn’t need to be. So you can leave it in dev mode, which will allow you as the app admin, resp. anyone else with a role in the app, to grant that permission without review.

Comment: Hey @CBroe, I already have a page access token, but i am unable to get the post details for my own page. My app is public though. I still get the same error, page public content access required

Comment: It works when the app is in dev mode. And from what I have read, it should work the same way when it is live - not sure if you might need to get `manage_pages` reviewed for that first though.